# Re-render many affected components after user signs out?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

As a part of my app, I want to re-render many components (profile image, content, etc.) when the user logs out. There are many components that will need to be re-rendered, but I'm not sure how to make this happen because the components are separate and there doesn't seem to be a clean logical way to force a re-rendering of everything affected.

Right now, I am using `useAuthenticator` and `Auth` from AWS in order to manage Cognito authentication. The only solution I can think of is to use a state/authentication hook at the App level and pass this down through all the components such that when the authentication state changes, the components affected will all re-render.

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: You need a global state to keep track of your authenticated state.  Either that or prop drill until your fingers bleed.  Look at useContext: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Is there a recommended way of doing it? Is it generally done through setting environment variables?